# How to parse betting odds data from api to create pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, parsing

I am new to coding and just learning about api's and json. My hope is create a pandas dataframe that looks like the following output:

```
Name            Over        Line      Under

Al Horford      -125         13        -103

Andrew Wiggins  -130         20        +100

etc.
```

I am able to scrape all of the player's names:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://betbuilder.digitalsportstech.com/api/feed'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
    'betType': 'in,18,19',
    'gameId': 'in,114109,114110,114111,114112,114113,114114',
    'isActive': '1',
    'limit': '9999',
    'sb': 'betonline',
    'tz': '-8'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

players_names = []

def get_names():
    data = jsonData['data']
    for d in data:
        name = d['player1']['name']
        print(name)
        players_names.append(d)

get_names()
```

I am unable to find the Over and Under betting data, however.

I am looking for 4 sources of data:

1) Name:  I was able to find the player's names with the output above.

2) Over: I cannot find this data.

3) Line: I was able to find this data under the title 'value'.

4) Under: I cannot find this data.

In summary I am looking for help locating the Over and Under data. I would then like to combine this data with the respective Name data and Line data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: doesn't look like those fields are returned in the API object. you're going to have to find them elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Under and Over data looks like it is there. It's within the `odds` key and is defined by the `betType`. `betType = 18` is `Under`, and `betType = 19` is `Over`.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests
import numpy as np



headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}


# Get Game IDs
url = 'https://betbuilder.digitalsportstech.com/api/latestGames'
payload = {
        'leagueId': '123',
        'order': 'asc',
        'sb': 'betonline',
        'sort': 'date',
        'status': 'in,1,2,3',
        'tz': '0'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
gameIds = []
for game in jsonData['data']:
    gameIds.append(str(game['id']))
gameIds = ','.join(gameIds)




# Get Player Data
url = 'https://betbuilder.digitalsportstech.com/api/feed'
payload = {
    'betType': 'in,18,19',
    'gameId': 'in,%s' %gameIds,
    'isActive': '1',
    'limit': '9999',
    'sb': 'betonline',
    'tz': '-8'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
if len(jsonData['data']) == 0:
    raise ValueError("O/U Markets for this league will be available as soon as possible\nCheck back soon")


def flatten_df(data):
    finalOutput = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        data = json_normalize(data)
        print ('Parsing the data...')
    except:
        data=data

    def unpack(temp_df, item):
        try:
            temp_df = json_normalize(item)
            return temp_df
        except:
            pass

    def iterrate(temp_df, row):
        for col, item in row.iteritems():
            if type(item) != list and type(item) != dict or col == 'statistic.phraseTitle':
                if len([ x for x in temp_df.columns if col.startswith(x) ]) > 0:
                        col = col + '_%s' %(len([ x for x in temp_df.columns if col.startswith(x) ]))
                try:
                    temp_df.loc[0,col] = item
                except:
                    temp_df.loc[0,col] = ', '.join(item)
                temp_df = temp_df.ffill()

            elif type(item) == list or type(item) == dict:
                temp_dfa = unpack(temp_df, item)
                temp_dfa.columns = col + '_' + temp_dfa.columns
                idxList = list(temp_df.index.values)
                alpha = temp_dfa.copy()
                merge_df = pd.DataFrame()
                for idx in idxList:
                    alpha.index = [idx]*len(alpha)
                    merge_df = merge_df.append(alpha, sort=False)


                temp_df = pd.merge(temp_df, merge_df, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
                temp_df = temp_df.reset_index(drop=True)
        return temp_df

    for idx, row in data.iterrows():
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
        finalOutput = finalOutput.append(iterrate(temp_df, row),sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    continueUnpacking = False
    for idx, row in finalOutput.iterrows():
        if len([ x for x, y in row.iteritems() if type(y) == list or type(y) == dict ]) > 0:
            print ('Still untangling...')
            continueUnpacking = True
            break

    if continueUnpacking == True:
        finalOutput = flatten_df(finalOutput)  


    return finalOutput

results = flatten_df(jsonData['data']) 




playersData = {}
for idx, row in results.iterrows():
    if row['player1.name'] not in list(playersData.keys()):
        playersData[row['player1.name']] = {}

    if row['statistic.title'] not in list(playersData[row['player1.name']].keys()):
        playersData[row['player1.name']][row['statistic.title']] = {'Line': row['markets_value']}

    # Under
    if row['betType'] == 18:
        playersData[row['player1.name']][row['statistic.title']].update({'Under': row['markets_odds']})

    # Over
    if row['betType'] == 19:
        playersData[row['player1.name']][row['statistic.title']].update({'Over': row['markets_odds']})

df = pd.DataFrame()
for player, v in playersData.items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(v).T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'statistic.title'})
    temp_df['Name'] = player
    temp_df = temp_df[['Name', 'statistic.title', 'Under', 'Line', 'Over']]
    df = df.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

Here's the site, and the matching output data:

[image]

```
print (df)
               Name               statistic.title  Under  Line  Over
0   Devonte' Graham               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.90  28.0  1.86
1   Devonte' Graham  Three Point Field Goals Made   1.67   2.5  2.15
2   Devonte' Graham                        Points   1.86  17.5  1.90
3   Devonte' Graham                       Assists   1.65   6.5  2.18
4     Miles Bridges               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.88  24.0  1.88
5     Miles Bridges  Three Point Field Goals Made   1.85   1.5  1.91
6     Miles Bridges                Total Rebounds   1.88   6.0  1.88
7     Miles Bridges                        Points   1.81  15.5  1.96
8        Trae Young                       Assists   1.70   9.5  2.10
9        Trae Young  Three Point Field Goals Made   2.15   3.5  1.67
10       Trae Young               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.87  41.5  1.89
11       Trae Young                        Points   1.89  27.5  1.87
12    Kevin Huerter                        Points   1.92  13.5  1.84
13    Kevin Huerter  Three Point Field Goals Made   2.04   2.5  1.74
14    Kevin Huerter               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.85  21.5  1.91
15     Terry Rozier                        Points   1.95  19.5  1.81
16     Terry Rozier               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.88  27.5  1.88
17     Terry Rozier                Total Rebounds   2.24   4.5  1.62
18     Terry Rozier  Three Point Field Goals Made   1.95   2.5  1.81
19      Cody Zeller                        Points   1.77  10.5  2.00
20      Cody Zeller                Total Rebounds   1.74   6.5  2.05
21      Cody Zeller               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.82  19.5  1.94
22     John Collins                Total Rebounds   1.77   9.5  2.00
23     John Collins  Three Point Field Goals Made   2.12   1.5  1.69
24     John Collins               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.85  34.5  1.91
25     John Collins                        Points   1.86  22.5  1.90
26  P.J. Washington  Three Point Field Goals Made   1.88   1.5  1.88
27  P.J. Washington                Total Rebounds   1.91   5.5  1.85
28  P.J. Washington               Pts + Reb + Ast   1.80  21.5  1.97
29  P.J. Washington                        Points   1.84  13.5  1.92
```

Comment: Thank you so much @chitown88! This is far beyond my current understanding. I will learn a lot from this and for that I am so grateful. =)